# Not authorized, skipping filter predicate application

Tags: ios, swift3, plist, ios10, mpmusicplayercontroller

Upon launch on an iOS10 device, I get the following output:

[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

[SDKPlayback] MPMusicPlayerController] MPMusicPlayerController: Server is not running, deferring check-in

[SDKLibrary] Not authorized, skipping filter predicate application

The app plays music from the user's library and therefore must ask permission, so I have updated info.plist with the required key strings for NSAppleMusicUsageDescription but the app crashes as soon as the predicate is called.  When the app is stopped and the launch screen disappears, the permission window is finally displayed.  If I tap allow, subsequent launches will work just fine.

My question is:  Does the "server not running" error have anything to do with the permissions window not being shown?  If so, how do I start it?

Comment: The output mentioned above is produced when running on a device (iPhone 6s+), not in the simulator.

Comment: Also, this is a systemMusicPlayer, not an applicationMusicPlayer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, the way an MPMusicPlayerController works is:

1. You have to have the key in the *Info.plist*, as you already know.
2. In your code, check authorization with `MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus`.
3. If you don't have authorization, you request authorization using `MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization`. You cannot proceed until you have authorization. Be careful because the call is *asynchronous* and the completion is called *on a background thread*.
4. Now you make an MPMediaItemCollection and call `setQueue(with:)` and then `play`.

Comment: This is what I was missing.  I'm leaving this comment since I don't have the reputation needed to mark an answer.

Comment: @matt: Thank you for the support. How can I play a particular song from the list.